# Test : Click (fireEvent.click) on Link in react-router-dom with react-testing-library doesn't trigger

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am testing Link from 'react-router-dom' with react-testing-library.

Normaly clicking on this link, should appears `linkId` on the page.

But fireEvent.click on my tests, does not trigger the action. Therefore I have not my content.

```
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link  data-testid="item" to={generatePath(LINK_TEST, { linkId: 'Link_test1' })}>Link Test 1</Link>
        </li>
... test : 

    const linkButton = getByText(/Link Test 1/)

    fireEvent.click(linkButton)

    const content = queryAllByText(/Page : Link_test1/)
    await waitForElement(() => content)
    expect(content).toHaveLength(1)
```

Comment: If you do `await waitForElement(() => getAllByText(/Page : Link_test1/))` does it change?

Comment: No, Unable to find an element with the text: /Page : Link_test1/.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not too late to give my input:

You are initiating a click, but are not specifying with which button you are clicking. Your line of code should look like that:

```
  fireEvent.click(linkButton, { button: 0});
```

As `button: 0` means 'left-click'. Hope this helps.

Edit: Additionally, I don't think `await` is needed in this case. If this is some piece of the whole code, you may indeed need it, but in a similar case I just fire the click event and then check if what I'm expecting to be in the document IS in the document, like:

```
expect(getByText('Page : Link_test1')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Or something like that, as I'm not exactly sure what are you expecting after the link click. Note that `.toBeInTheDocument()` is a method from `'@testing-library/jest-dom'` and is imported as

```
'@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
```

Comment: { button: 0 } is the default for fireEvent.click, so that's not the issue

Answer (score 1):

I have been hitting this issue with ALL links (I'm not using react-router-dom).  But one way I got around it was to actually set the URL with `window.location.href = linkHref`.

When I did that, then it triggered the event handlers I have setup.

Not sure if this helps in the slightest, but wanted to mention it as a possible work-around.  Your `linkButton` will have an `href` property you can snag.