# fireEvent.click() on NavLink not triggering history.push() in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-router, mouseevent, react-testing-library

I'm trying to verify that a certain route is called after clicking a link that is generated after an async api call. I tested for the occurrence of the link and the correct href attribute beforehand and now want to simulate a user click on the react NavLink (mocking the methods that should be called by the click).

It seems neither history.push() nor handleClick() are being called by the fireEvent. I always get this error:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

I tried adding the mouse button and bubbling (according to [Test : Click (fireEvent.click) on Link in react-router-dom with react-testing-library doesn't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356433/test-click-fireevent-click-on-link-in-react-router-dom-with-react-testing-li) and other posts), without success. Here's the code:

```
import {findByTestId, fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import Card from "./Card";

test('click on card leads to newgame/gameName route', async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    history.push = jest.fn();
    render(<MemoryRouter history={history}><Card element={{name: "3ts", title: "3Ts", description: "Tic Tac Toe"}}/></MemoryRouter>);
    const card = await screen.findByTestId('card-link');
    expect(card).toHaveAttribute('href', '/newGame/3ts');
    card.handleClick = jest.fn(); // I tried this after history.push didn't seem to work
    fireEvent(card, new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true})); // I tried adding bubbling after I read another user's situation where this helped.

    expect(card.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(history.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, show the code of the `Card` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test a single component in a *MemoryWrapper* you have to configure some *Routes* as shown in the [docu](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/memory-router). It depends on your testing goal but if you have a *NavLink* in your *Card* component that routes to "*aGame*" url your test could look like this:

```
test('click card and jump to agame', async () => {
//arrange
render(<MemoryRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Card
            element={
                {
                    name: "aName",
                    title: "a Title",
                    description: "A description",
                }
            }
        />}/>
        <Route path="/aGame/:something" element={<NewGame/>}/>
    </Routes>
</MemoryRouter>);

let navLink = await screen.findByTestId('card-link');

//act
fireEvent.click(navLink);

//assert
let aGameDiv = screen.getByTestId('agame');
expect(aGameDiv).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

If you want to test your routing setup, you should test this in App.js or wherever the routing setup happens.